# Html triangle with 100% width

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to create a blurred triangle shape on each selected thumbnail image in a grid.

For now I'm doing it like this (the triangle and it's div container):

```
:host ::ng-deep {

    .blurred-triangle {
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 0 400px 200px 0;
          border-color: transparent rgba(250, 248, 255, 0.2) transparent transparent;
        }

    .dashboard-image-selected__container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

My issue is the width of the triangle. If the image is too large the triangle don't fill the width.

How can I use something like 100% width for this triangle shape so that it fills exactly the width of it's parent ?

Comment: You could try using object-fit on the image. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Comment: I think you missunderstood my issue, it's not related to the image but to the selection overlay that is a blurred triangle shape.

Comment: can you share your html also, and the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vw` to make the css triangle responsive. It will set the width of the triangle based on the width of the screen.

It may be better to use something like calc(30vw + 100px) and calc(15vw + 50px) if you need to set a minimum width for any reason. However this will make the triangle larger than the container so you'll need to use `overflow: hidden` in this case.

```css
.blurred-triangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 30vw 15vw 0;
  border-color: transparent rgba(250, 248, 255, 0.32) transparent transparent;
}

.dashboard-image-selected__container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-image-selected__container">
  <div class="blurred-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like the following:

```css
img {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

img:hover {
  opacity: .8
}
```

```html
<img src="//cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/20/22/43/adler-3551609_960_720.jpg">
```

Comment: Ah, clip-path. I used that a while back when it was first coming out. How well is this supported these days?

Comment: @Sarcoma according to https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path not really great if you want to support IE/ edge that is .

Comment: Good solution, just be aware that it's not yet supported in Edge and IE 11: https://caniuse.com/#search=clip

Comment: Interresting solution. but IE support is important in my case. Also is it possible to tweak opacity here ? In my case the shape should only create a glass effect, not hide completly the image.

Comment: @An-droid check the update to confirm that it is possible to add opacity.